# Use custom init method when programmatically creating a uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Due to the limitations of Storyboard I am creating a UICollectionView programmatically. This is working all fine and when I want to add a `UICollectionViewCell` I do the following:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
```

What I was wondering is how can I use a custom init method from the class "Cell", because I can't do something like the following:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[[Cell class]init_custom]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
```

Question: How can I use a custom init method from a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of specifying a different init method. Why is overloading `-init` not working?

Comment: Because I make multiple collectionviews in one uiview and it would make it much more readable when creating more init methods. then one who detects which one is calling.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you are saying. I think you want to use your custom collection view cell for different collection views and you want to better customize the cell's init method for the different collection views.

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear enough. Because it is a whole project with may lines of code it is hard to explain it without posting the whole project. But what you think right I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then I would create subclasses of your collection view cell.

First setup your cell with everything you want.

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
// Your custom cell
@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell
// Your custom cell
@end
```

Then for each collection view create a subclass which only overrides init.

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView1 : MyCollectionViewCell

@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView1
- (instancetype)init // Only override -init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Setup for collection view one
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@interface MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView2 : MyCollectionViewCell

@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView2
- (instancetype)init // Only override -init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Setup for collection view two
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then for each different collection view, you register one of your subclasses.

```
[collectionView1 registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView1 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
[collectionView2 registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCellForCollectionView2 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
```

This will get you the separate custom init methods you wish, but be sure to keep all your functionality in the base class.

Comment: So its not possible to pass parameters within those overrided init methods?
Like title or colours?

Comment: @Konstantin It's not possible. The initialization is controlled by the collection view. Only `init(frame:)` or `init(coder:)` will be called.

Comment: @Konstantin You can either subclass, or have a setup method that would need to be called from `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`